# date time stored as varchar in sql how to filter on varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I am working on a project in which dates and times ar stored as a varchar e.g. "30-11-2017,7:30" first date in dd-mm-yyy format and then time separated with a comma.  I am trying to filter on it but it is not working correctly kindly guide me how to filter data on date.

```
select *
from timetrack
where startDateAndTime >= '30-11-2017,7:30'
```

In attached image records have been shown.  When I apply above query it shows no records

Comment: MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? You've tagged both.

Comment: Firstly, `mysql` or `sql-server` (they are not one and the same)? Secondly, your problem is that your storing dates as a string, the simple answer is **don't**. Store your dates as dates, for the simple reason your having here; simple queries dont work. As a example, in varchars the "date" `'30-11-2017'` is **AFTER** `01-12-2052'`.

Comment: i am using sql server the reason is now cannot change it to date if can filter in this case

Comment: Well said @Larnu.  If you don't store dates and times in the proper data types you will run into issue, after issue.  Any time lost refactoring now will be outweighed by the time saved later on.

Comment: If you can't change your datatype, you're going to have problems; simply said. Are you able to change the DDL of the table? We could consider adding a Computed Column so you could query against instead. The problem with that, however, is that you can't `PERSIST` a column with a `CONVERT`/`CAST`, so you won't be able to `INDEX` it; meaning you'll suffer the same poor performance as converting the value in a query (but at least it's in the table, rather than you having to convert it in every query against the table). But, please consider changing your data type; that's the **real** answer here.

Comment: Also, which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily convert your date to SQL datatype `datetime` uisng `parse` function, for example `select parse('30-11-2017,7:30' as datetime using 'it-IT')`.

So, in your case, you can apply this function in `where` clause, so you can easily apply comparison between dates:

```
select *
from timetrack
where parse(startDateAndTime as datetime using 'it-IT') >= '2017-11-30 07:30:00.000'
```

Your format is apparently italian :) But you have to specify your own date in the format convertable to `datetime`, as I have done in above example.

NOTE: `parse` is available starting with SQL Management Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using ISO date format (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or close) applying ordering (which inequalities like greater than or equal use) will not work: the date order is disconnected from the string ordering.

You'll need to parse the date and times into a real date time type and then compare to that (details of this depend on which RDBMS you are using).

Answer (score 0):

If, you want to just filter out the date then you could use `convert()` function for SQL Server

```
select *
from timetrack
where startDateAndTime >= convert(date, left(@date, 10), 103)
```

Else convert it to datetime as follow

```
select *
from timetrack
where startDateAndTime >= convert(datetime, left(@date, 10)+' ' +
    reverse(left(reverse(@date), charindex(',', reverse(@date))-1)), 103)
```

Comment: You realise that using a style code with `CONVERT(date,...` doesn't do anything right? :) Style codes are specifically when converting to a `(n)varchar`. `CONVERT(date, GETDATE(),103)` and `CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 155)` would yield the exact same result (155 isn't even a valid style code, so it's completely ignored).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to check what is the data that is entered in the 'startDateAndTime' column,then you can convert that varchar into date format

If the data in `'startDateAndTime'` column has data like `'30-11-2017,07:30'`, you would then have to convert it into date:

```
SELECT to_date('30-11-2017,07:30','dd-mm-yyyy,hh:mm') from dual; --check this
```

--Your query:

```
SELECT to_date(startDateAndTime ,'dd-mm-yyyy,hh:mm') from timetrack;
```

Comment: dual is dummy table for `Oracle` and here is `SQL Server`.. how the above resolved the issue ??

Comment: One would then need to convert the varchar format to date format anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You need the date in a datetime column, Otherwise you can't filter with your current varchar format of your date.

Without changing the existing columns, this can be achieved by making a computed column and making it persisted to optimize performance.

```
ALTER TABLE test add CstartDateTime 
  as convert(datetime, substring(startDateAndTime, 7,4)+ substring(startDateAndTime, 4,2)
     + left(startDateAndTime, 2) +' '+ right(startDateAndTime, 5), 112) persisted
```

Note: this require all rows in the column contains a valid date with the current format